# позиционирование с помощью флексов

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Проблема в чём ни как не могу разместить надпись 300 долларов с права возле корзины, и не знаю как переместить надпись. А с флексами только начал работать. Хочу что бы получилось примерно так

[image: Хочу что бы получилось примерно так]

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.whaper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #3cc3b5;
}

.korzina {}


/*
.dolar{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -75px;
    left: -80px;
}

.dolar h2{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 300;
} 
*/


/*Search form*/

.search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Это включает позиционирование относительно <form>, */
  /* а не относительно всей страницы */
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 435px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*and search form*/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="whaper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1>Aditii</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        <form action="#" class="search-form">
          <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
          <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
             <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
             <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="korzina">
        <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/13/8a7753a627c0f71b8149eb94c44dd162-full.png" alt="">
        <h2>$300</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.korzina {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.korzina img, .korzina h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.whaper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #3cc3b5;
}

.korzina {}


/*
.dolar{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -75px;
    left: -80px;
}

.dolar h2{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 300;
} 
*/


/*Search form*/

.search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Это включает позиционирование относительно <form>, */
  /* а не относительно всей страницы */
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 435px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*and search form*/

.korzina {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.korzina img, .korzina h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="whaper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1>Aditii</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        <form action="#" class="search-form">
          <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
          <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
             <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
             <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="korzina">
        <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/13/8a7753a627c0f71b8149eb94c44dd162-full.png" alt="">
        <h2>$300</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```